# How to generate a query using an array of delimited columns & values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, where-in

I have this array:

```
$filter=['color*black','color*blue','color*red','paint*apex','paint*dalton'];
```

Each value in `$filter` has two substrings separated by `*`.  The first substring represents a database table column and the second represents a desired value for that column.

My `products` table looks like this:

```
id    name    color    paint
1     p1      black     compo
2     p2      red       dalton
3     p3      pink      apex
4     p4      blue      apex
5     p5      cream     compo
```

Using `$filter`, I need to search the `products` table and return all rows with a `paint` value of `apex` or `dalton` AND a `color` value of `black`, `blue`, or `red`.

The desired output is a mysql query that will only return these rows:

```
id    name    color    paint
2     p2      red       dalton
4     p4      blue      apex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You need to construct a query like this `SELECT * FROM products WHERE (color IN ('black', 'blue', 'red')) AND (paint IN ('apex', 'dalton'))`, then the code below might be useful (please, check it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9692aa9b94e6de2aad1e67502e5a2040fc8785af)):

```
$filter = array(
    0 => "color*black",
    1 => "color*blue",
    2 => "color*red",
    3 => "paint*apex",
    4 => "paint*dalton"
);

$elements = [];

foreach ($filter as $value) {
    list($before, $after) = explode('*', $value);
    $elements[$before][] = $after;
}

$parts = [];

foreach ($elements as $column => $values) {
    $parts[] = "(`$column` IN ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "'))";
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $parts);
```

Running this query against the given table data structure:

```
id    name    color    paint
1     p1      black     compo
2     p2      red       dalton
3     p3      pink      apex
4     p4      blue      apex
5     p5      cream     compo
```

will match the following rows:

```
2     p2      red       dalton
4     p4      blue      apex
```

Comment: could you please run this with given table structure and entry .

Comment: @abilasher I've checked [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602309/making-a-proper-image-capture-of-screen-using-jquery), but, unfortunately can't help you with it..

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using `explode`, `foreach` and `array_values` to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788353)

```
<?php

$filter = array(
    0 => "color*black",
    1 => "color*blue",
    2 => "color*red",
    3 => "paint*apex",
    4 => "paint*dalton");

$result=array();
foreach($filter as $value)
{
    list($before,$after)=explode("*",$value);
    $result["before"][$before]=$before;
    $result["after"][$after]=$after;
}
$result["before"]=  array_values($result["before"]);
$result["after"]=  array_values($result["after"]);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [before] => Array
        (
            [0] => color
            [1] => paint
        )
    [after] => Array
        (
            [0] => black
            [1] => blue
            [2] => red
            [3] => apex
            [4] => dalton
        )
)
```

Comment: could you please tell how can i perform the sql operation .

Comment: @abilasher You can try this one.. https://eval.in/788364 in the last SQL query i have given OR i have changed it to AND conditions between color and paint.