# Making a proper image capture of Current screen using jquery Or PHP or Convert div to pdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phantomjs

I write some code for to convert svg to inline svg and take screenshot of that div . Please check .Please copy this code int to your local host and test it . Because screen shot is different in different width .

https://jsfiddle.net/7bqukhff/15/

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/canvg/canvg/master/canvg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="test">
    <div class="description-div">

    <p>Sample description</p>

    </div>



      <div class="img-div" id="img-div"></div>


</div>

 <form class="cf">
      <div class="half left cf">
        <input type="text"  name="user-name" required>
         <select name="design-name" class="desgign-class" required>
             <option value="" >select</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
             <option>4</option>
         </select> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit"> 

      </div>

   </form>


</div>
<div class="new">
 <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="generate();">Generate Screenshot »</a>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {

$(".desgign-class").on("change",function(){

 var op=$(this).val();

  if(op!=0){
  $('.btn').show();
  $('.img-div').html('');
  if(op==2){
             for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
                $('.img-div').append("<img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/1tf.svg'>");
             } 
    }

    if(op==3){
              for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
                 $('.img-div').append("<img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/_1tf.svg'>");
              }
    }

      if(op==4){
              for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
                 $('.img-div').append("<img src='http://svgur.com//i/1yP.svg'>");
              }
    }

    }

    else{
    $('.btn').hide();
    }

     $('img').each(function() {

      var $img = jQuery(this);
      var imgID = $img.attr('id');
      var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
      var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

      jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
         var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
         }
         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
         }
         // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
         $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

         // Replace image with new SVG
         $img.replaceWith($svg);

      }, 'xml');

   });
});

(function(exports) {
   function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
      if (!nodeList.length) {
         return [];
      }
      var attrName = 'href';
      if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
         attrName = 'src';
      }
      nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
         var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
         if (!attr) {
            return;
         }
         var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
         if (absURL) {
            return el;
         } else {
            return el;
         }
      });
      return nodeList;
   }

   function screenshotPage() {
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('img-div');
      html2canvas(wrapper, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
            function getOffset(el) {
               el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
               return {
                  left: el.left + window.scrollX,
                  top: el.top + window.scrollY
               }
            }
            var cachedCanvas = canvas;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
            svgs.forEach(function(svg) {
               var svgWidth = svg.width.baseVal.value;
               var svgHeight = svg.height.baseVal.value;
               var svgLeft = getOffset(svg).left - 40;
               var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - 62;
               var offScreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
               offScreenCanvas.width = svgWidth;
               offScreenCanvas.height = svgHeight;
               canvg(offScreenCanvas, svg.outerHTML);
               ctx.drawImage(cachedCanvas, 0, 0);
               ctx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, svgLeft, svgTop);
            });
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
               saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
            });
         }
      });
   }

   function addOnPageLoad_() {
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
         var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
         var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
         window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      });
   }

   function generate() {
      screenshotPage();
   }
   exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
   exports.generate = generate;
})(window);

});



</script>

html,
body {
   background: #f1f1f1;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   padding: 1em;
}


form {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}

.img-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 86px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.btn {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.new{
     display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.description-div {
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 32px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 13%;
}

.submit {
    background: wheat none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input,
textarea {
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   padding: 1em;
   @include border-radius(8px);
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 1em;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(black, 0.1));
   resize: none;
   &:focus {
      @include box-shadow(0 0px 2px rgba($red, 1)!important);
   }
}

#input-submit {
   color: white;
   background: $red;
   cursor: pointer;
   &:hover {
      @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px 1px rgba(#aaa, 0.6));
   }
}
```

But here **(1)** when i take screen shot of `img-div` the screenshot is different from original representation.   Why it happen ?

**(2)** Also in option 4 screenshot the svg is not appearing  . Actually i have too many option and too many images . Now i only write 3 options .

**(3)** Is it possible for to save this screen shot to server[specific folder] when user submitting the form ?

**(4)** Is there any other method without using html canvas ?

**(5)** LIKE HOW SCREEN SHOT OPTION IN COMPUTER WORKS ? or browser extension like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj?hl=en .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3766n-SDPNc&feature=youtu.be

> Short form : i have a website . In which user can select any svg from
>   the given svg list . When user select one svg then that svg is
>   converted to inline svg  displayed in one div . Also user can move
>   that svg to any portion of the div . After everything then user will
>   fill a form and submit . At the time of submit we want to download the
>   screen shot of that div then we understand user select which colour ,
>   where the svg imge is place etc

Comment: i downloaded phantomjs. But it's difficult to understand what to do

Comment: ok . it will work in my web server ? . so i need to install  this on the server &  irrespective of client browser or device it will work correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below mentioned solution. I just tried to cover up your issue.

```js
$(function() {

$(".desgign-class").on("change",function(){
 
 var op=$(this).val();
 
  if(op!=0){
  $('.btn').show();
  $('.img-div').html('');
  if(op==2){
    for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
    $('.img-div').append("<img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/1tf.svg'>");
    } 
 }
  
    if(op==3){
     for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
     $('.img-div').append("<img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/_1tf.svg'>");
     }
    }
 
   if(op==4){
     for(var i = 0;i<op;i++){
     $('.img-div').append("<img src='http://svgur.com//i/1yP.svg'>");
     }
    }
 
 }
 
 else{
 $('.btn').hide();
 }
 
  $('img').each(function() {

      var $img = jQuery(this);
      var imgID = $img.attr('id');
      var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
      var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

      jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
         var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
         }
         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
         }
         // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
         $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

         // Replace image with new SVG
         $img.replaceWith($svg);

      }, 'xml');

   });
});

(function(exports) {
   function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
      if (!nodeList.length) {
         return [];
      }
      var attrName = 'href';
      if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
         attrName = 'src';
      }
      nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
         var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
         if (!attr) {
            return;
         }
         var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
         if (absURL) {
            return el;
         } else {
            return el;
         }
      });
      return nodeList;
   }

   function screenshotPage() {
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('img-div');
      html2canvas(wrapper, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
            function getOffset(el) {
               el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
               return {
                  left: el.left + window.scrollX,
                  top: el.top + window.scrollY
               }
            }
            var cachedCanvas = canvas;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
            var sleft = 0;
            svgs.forEach(function(svg) {
               var svgWidth = svg.width.baseVal.value;
               var svgHeight = svg.height.baseVal.value;
               var svgLeft = 10;
               var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - 40;
               var offScreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
               offScreenCanvas.width = svgWidth;
               offScreenCanvas.height = svgHeight;
               canvg(offScreenCanvas, svg.outerHTML);
               ctx.drawImage(cachedCanvas, 0, 0);
               ctx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, svgLeft, svgTop);
              
            });
            
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
               saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
            });
         }
      });
   }

   function addOnPageLoad_() {
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
         var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
         var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
         window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      });
   }

   function generate() {
      screenshotPage();
   }
   exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
   exports.generate = generate;
})(window);
 
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
$red: #e74c3c;
*,
*:before,
*:after {
   @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

html,
body {
   background: #f1f1f1;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   color: #a8a8a8;
   @include text-shadow(1px 1px 0 rgba(white, 1));
}

form {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}

.img-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 86px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
}
.btn {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.new{
  display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.description-div {
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 32px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 13%;
}

.submit {
    background: wheat none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input,
textarea {
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   padding: 1em;
   @include border-radius(8px);
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 1em;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(black, 0.1));
   resize: none;
   &:focus {
      @include box-shadow(0 0px 2px rgba($red, 1)!important);
   }
}

#input-submit {
   color: white;
   background: $red;
   cursor: pointer;
   &:hover {
      @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px 1px rgba(#aaa, 0.6));
   }
}

textarea {
   height: 126px;
}


}
.half {
   float: left;
   width: 48%;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.right {
   width: 50%;
}
.left {
   margin-right: 2%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .half {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      margin-bottom: 0;
   }
}

/* Clearfix */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
   content: " ";
   /* 1 */
   
   display: table;
   /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
   clear: both;
}
.half.left.cf > input {
   margin: 5px;
}
@media print {
    html, body { padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important; }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/canvg/canvg/master/canvg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="test">
 <div class="description-div">

 <p>Sample description</p>

 </div>

 

   <div class="img-div" id="img-div"></div>
    
 
</div>

 <form class="cf">
      <div class="half left cf">
        <input type="text"  name="user-name" required>
   <select name="design-name" class="desgign-class" required>
    <option value="" >select</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
   </select> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit"> 
   
      </div>
     
   </form>
   
    
</div>
<div class="new">
 <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="generate();">Generate Screenshot »</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you friend . Could you please give a short description for what you did

Comment: @abilasher : Glad to help you out from this hurdle. Eventually there is no error in perspective of code. 2 things I changed in your code. 1. When we do print, You have to add `@media print` queries.2. When you use SVG at that time you have to take care about position. There is error in your loop while creating SVG, `var svgLeft = 10;var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - 40;`, This is what I have changed.Again its not an easy task to do but you did a great Job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/7bqukhff/16/

The difference comes from the way you are drawing onto the `offscreenCanvas`.

Here's what happens in your code:

1. You are setting the dimensions of the `offscreenCanvas` to the width and height of the SVG (instead of the width & height of the wrapper) in lines 108 & 109
2. You subtract something (40 and 62) from the left & top position of the SVG. This position is referring to the position on the page rather than the relative position of the SVG within the wrapper.
3. You draw the SVG onto the canvas with page-coordinates instead of relative coordinates

The fix looks like this:

First, set the dimensions of the canvas to the dimensions of the wrapper:

```
var wrapperRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect()
// ...
offScreenCanvas.width = wrapperRect.width;
offScreenCanvas.height = wrapperRect.height;
```

Then, draw the svg using relative coordinates:

```
var svgLeft = getOffset(svg).left - wrapper.left;
var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - wrapper.top;
```

This seems to work as you need.

P.S.: The option "4" doesn't work but that's due to it using HTTP on an HTTPS site, so it's not loaded due to security restrictions.

Comment: Thank you friend  .I am aware of this, that's why i am looking for a solution without html2canvas . Also i subtract value , that is my mistake . But still it will not be proper solution for this problem .

Comment: To quote the question:

> At the time of submit we ant to download the screen shot of that div then we understand user select which colour , where the svg imge is place etc

I don't think there's a way to accomplish that without a canvas. Maybe with an extension, but that's not what you asked for.

Comment: so friend , what will be the solution for the current situation .?